# Why is this neural network not rendering (only) full 3-layer pathways?

Tags: javascript, canvas, neural-network

The function in question is rendering the neural network represented on the right side of this image based on a fairly simple data structure.

Trying to evolve:

[image]

After evolving:

[image]

Each dot represents a neuron, each line a connection. There's a problem with which neurons and connections are being rendered and which aren't, and I've been wrestling with this problem for 5 hours straight, no coffee breaks. One of you is likely going to point out one tiny stupid mistake causing the issue and I'll likely proceed to pull my hair out.

Put simply: Connections run from the top down. I only want to render complete paths from top to bottom. No dots (neurons) in the middle should be rendered if no connections lead to them from the top. If a top layer neuron connects to a middle layer neuron but that middle layer neuron doesn't connect to a bottom layer neuron, that connection isn't doing anything so it shouldn't be rendered.

As you can see, there are top level neurons that are rendered with no connections at all, and middle level neurons which are rendered with no connection to the top. All connections are top-down, no connections flow upward. The network is feed-forward in other words.

The data structure passed to this function is `brain` which is the same `brain` passed to the following `Neuron` and `Connection` constructors which are listed in abridged form only showing the properties relevant to the function in question (edited from the original with further attempts to fix the problem:

**Neuron**

```
function Neuron(brain, layer) {
    var that = this;
    brain.counter++;
    brain.globalReferenceNeurons[brain.counter] = this;
    this.active = true; //as the brain mutates, some neurons and 
    //connections are disabled via this property
    this.layer = layer;
    this.id = brain.counter;
    this.connected = {};
    this.connections = {};
    this.connect = function(target) {
        if (that.active == true) {
            new Connection(brain, this, target, function(id, connection) {
                brain.globalReferenceConnections[id] = connection;
                that.connections[id] = connection;
            });
        }
    };
}
```

**Connection**

```
function Connection(brain, source, target, callback) {
    if (source.layer < target.layer) {
        brain.counter++;
        brain.globalReferenceConnections[brain.counter] = this;
        this.active = true; //as the brain mutates, some neurons and 
        //connections are disabled via this property
        this.id = brain.counter;
        this.source = source;
        this.target = target;
        target.connected[this.id] = this; //connected references 
        //incoming connections to a neuron
        callback(this.id, this);
    }
}
```

As you can see, `brain.globalReferenceNeurons` contains the the data needed to render the neural network in the picture.

And here's the rendering function in question (updated again):

```
function renderBrain(brain, context, canvas) {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var width = canvas.width;
  var height = canvas.height;
  var layers = brain.layers;
  var heightDivision = height / layers;
  var layerList = [];
  for (var i1 = 0; i1 < brain.layers; i1++) {
    layerList.push([]);
    for (var prop1 in brain.globalReferenceNeurons) {
      if (brain.globalReferenceNeurons[prop1].layer === i1) {
        layerList[i1].push(brain.globalReferenceNeurons[prop1]);
      }
    }
  }

  function renderLayer(layer, layerCount, layerTotal) {
    var length = layer.length;
    var widthDivision = width / length;
    var neuronCount = 0;
    for (var i1 = 0; i1 < layer.length; i1++) {
      neuronCount++;
      const getActiveProps = obj => Object.keys(obj).filter(k => obj[k].active)

      function hasActivePathAhead(obj, count) {
        if (!count) {
          count = 0;
        }
        if (obj.active) {
          var targets = getActiveProps(obj.connections);
          if (obj.layer === 2) {
            return true;
          } else if (obj.connections[targets[count]]) {
            for (var i1 = 0; i1 < targets.length; i1++) {
              var result = hasActivePathAhead(obj.connections[targets[count]].target, 
                  count + 1);
              return result;
            }
            return false;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }

      function hasActivePathBehind(obj, count) {
        if (!count) {
          count = 0;
        }
        if (obj.active) {
          var sources = getActiveProps(obj.connected);
          if (obj.layer === 0) {
            return true;
          } else if (obj.connected[sources[count]]) {
            for (var i1 = 0; i1 < sources.length; i1++) {
              var result = 
                  hasActivePathBehind(obj.connected[sources[count]].source, count + 1);
              return result;
            }
            return false;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }
      if (hasActivePathAhead(layer[i1]) && hasActivePathBehind(layer[i1])) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc((widthDivision * neuronCount) 
            - (0.5 * widthDivision), 
            (heightDivision * layerCount) 
            - (heightDivision * 0.5), 
            5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        context.fillStyle = '#adf442';
        context.fill();
        context.lineWidth = 2;
        context.strokeStyle = '#56cc41';
        context.stroke();
        var connectionCount = 0;
        for (var i2 = 0; i2 < Object.keys(layer[i1].connections).length; i2++) {
          var connection = 
              layer[i1].connections[Object.keys(layer[i1].connections)[i2]];
          if (hasActivePathAhead(connection.target) 
              && hasActivePathBehind(connection.target)) {
            var targetLayer = connection.target.layer;
            var index = layerList[targetLayer].findIndex(function(e) {
              return e == connection.target
            });
            if (index > -1) {
              var targetLayerLength = Object.keys(layerList[targetLayer]).length;
              var targetLayerWidthDivision = width / targetLayerLength;
              var p1 = {
                x: (widthDivision * neuronCount) - (0.5 * widthDivision),
                y: (heightDivision * layerCount) - (heightDivision * 0.5)
              };
              var p2 = {
                x: (index * targetLayerWidthDivision) 
                    + (0.5 * targetLayerWidthDivision),
                y: (targetLayer * heightDivision) 
                    + (heightDivision * 0.5)
              };
              connectionCount++;
              context.beginPath();
              context.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
              context.lineTo(p2.x, p2.y);
              context.lineWidth = 1;
              context.stroke();
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  var layerCount = 0;
  for (i1 = 0; i1 < layerList.length; i1++) {
    layerCount++;
    renderLayer(layerList[i1], layerCount, layerList.length);
  }
}
```

"Working" test example: https://jsfiddle.net/au2Lt6na/4/

For 5 hours I've tinkered with this function trying to pinpoint the issue and for the life of me I haven't been able to figure it out. Can anyone tell me what's causing the rendering of non-top-to-bottom neural pathways?

---

Note: I've spent many more hours over the past few days trying to fix this, writing totally new ways of figuring out which paths are complete from top to bottom and it still suffers from the same issues as before. I'm missing something here.

Comment: By the way I realize this probably isn't great SE etiquette to solicit collaborators, but if anyone happens to be interested and is pretty good with JS, I've been looking for someone to collaborate with on the project. The goal is to have the network teach itself to play Mario NES games.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: @Arg0n ehh. This is a tough one. Here I am asking you guys to help me figure out a problem with a fairly big chunk of code, and I'm trying not to provide the full source code. The thing is, I'm planning on attempting to profit from the result of this project by creating Twitch and YouTube channels that publish videos of this neural network learning and playing hundreds of different NES games, and if I publish the source code (which is already capable of playing Mario Bros) anyone can take it and compete with me. I feel bad asking for help but simultaneously saying "no, you cant see my source".

Comment: I see, fixing code that's a bit more complex is usually (for me) done by trial and error, debugging etc.

Comment: @Arg0n I posted in case some of you gurus could spot the issue without an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - if not I'll have to figure it out. That's why it's better to work on these kinds of projects with a collaborator, just havent been able to locate someone A) interested B) reliable and C) skilled.

Comment: So `As you can see, there are top level neurons that are rendered with no connections at all, and middle level neurons which are rendered with no connection to the top.` is not want you want, right? If it is, please figure out what you want.

Comment: @blackmiaool I'm not sure I understand your confusion. I want to only render paths (including both connections and neurons) which strictly run from top to bottom fully. Connection paths only go from top to bottom. None of the lines you see connect "upwards" - it's all top-down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Could not fit into the comment and as you do not have a working example we can only guess.</strike>

Your recursion does not look right to me. The count variable makes no sense and you have several levels of redundancy checking for active 3 times for each iteration  and not vetting when indexing into the key arrays with `count`.

Without working code and as your variable nomenclature is confusing this is only a guess at how to fix. Same applies to `hasActivePathBehind`

*Ignore the following code*

```js
 function hasActivePathAhead(obj) {
    if (obj.active) {
        if (obj.layer === 2) {
            return true;
        }
        var targets = getActiveProps(obj.connections);
        for (var i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
            if(hasActivePathAhead(obj.connections[targets[i]].target)){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
 }
```

---

#### UPDATE and working fix.

Update **because accepted answer does not work**, it should have used a more rigorous test.

As you have provided a fiddle in the comments I had a look as see that you have removed the count from the functions. Though the functions are still incorrect and not working, the error is elsewhere in the code. The code is overly complex hiding the nature of the bug.

There is too much wrong to go into detail so I have just started from scratch.

Rather than test every node for a backward and forward link I traverse the layers forward from top to bottom. This negates the need to check backward connections. I have a function that checks if a node is connected to the bottom, a function that draws all nodes from a node to the bottom, and a function that draws all active nodes at a layer (active is connected from that layer down)

You can optimise it by adding a flag to nodes indicating that they have already been rendered as the code as is can render some nodes several times. But I did not add that as I did not want to modify the data structure you had. Or you can add a `Map` that holds node pairs that have been rendered and check that to see if a node pair needs to be rendered.

Using your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/au2Lt6na/4/) as a template here is a working version using the randomised paths as provided in the fiddle.

```js
function Neuron(brain, layer) {
    var that = this;
    brain.counter++;
    brain.globalReferenceNeurons[brain.counter] = this;
    this.active = true; //as the brain mutates, some neurons and 
    //connections are disabled via this property
    this.layer = layer;
    this.id = brain.counter;
    this.connected = {};
    this.connections = {};
    this.connect = function (target) {
        if (that.active == true) {
            new Connection(brain, this, target, function (id, connection) {
                brain.globalReferenceConnections[id] = connection;
                that.connections[id] = connection;
            });
        }
    };
}

function Connection(brain, source, target, callback) {
    if (source.layer < target.layer) {
        brain.counter++;
        brain.globalReferenceConnections[brain.counter] = this;
        this.active = true; //as the brain mutates, some neurons and 
        //connections are disabled via this property
        this.id = brain.counter;
        this.source = source;
        this.target = target;
        target.connected[this.id] = this;
        callback(this.id, this);
    }
}


function renderBrain(brain, ctx, canvas) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var width = canvas.width;
    var height = canvas.height;
    var layers = brain.layers;
    var heightDiv = height / layers;
    var layerList = [];
    for (var i1 = 0; i1 < brain.layers; i1++) {
        layerList.push([]);
        for (var prop1 in brain.globalReferenceNeurons) {
            if (brain.globalReferenceNeurons[prop1].layer === i1) {
                layerList[i1].push(brain.globalReferenceNeurons[prop1]);
            }
        }
    }
    var coord;  // to hold node coordinates defined here to prevent pointless memory allocation dealocation cycle
    // Gets the node position based on its ID and layer position
    function nodePosition(node,coord = {}){
        var pos;
        pos = node.id - layerList[node.layer][0].id; // get pos from node id (if this does not hold true you should include the node position in the node data is it is important)
        coord.x = (width / layerList[node.layer].length) * (pos + 0.5);
        coord.y = heightDiv * (node.layer + 0.5);
        return coord;
    }        
    // draws a node
    function drawNode(node){
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#56cc41';
        ctx.fillStyle = '#adf442';
        ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        coord = nodePosition(node,coord);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(coord.x,coord.y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    // draws a link between two nodes
    function drawLink(node,node1){
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#56cc41';
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        coord = nodePosition(node,coord);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(coord.x,coord.y);
        coord = nodePosition(node1,coord);
        ctx.lineTo(coord.x,coord.y);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    // returns true if the path from this node jas a connection that leads to the end
    function isPathActive(node){
        var paths, i, nextNode;
        if(node.active){
            if(node.layer === 2){ // is node at end
                return true;
            }
            paths = Object.keys(node.connections).map(key => node.connections[key]);
            for(i = 0; i < paths.length; i ++){
                nextNode = paths[i].target;
                if(nextNode.active){
                    if(nextNode.layer === 2){
                        return true;
                    }
                    if(isPathActive(nextNode)){
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    // renders from a node all active pathes to end
    function renderPath(node){
        var i;
        paths = Object.keys(node.connections).map(key => node.connections[key]);
        for(i = 0; i < paths.length; i ++){
            nextNode = paths[i].target;
            if(isPathActive(nextNode)){
                drawLink(node,nextNode)
                renderPath(nextNode);
            }
        }
        drawNode(node,i+ 1)
    }
    // renders from top layer all active paths
    function renderActivePaths(layer){
        var i;
        for(i = 0; i < layer.length; i ++){
            if(isPathActive(layer[i])){
                renderPath(layer[i])
            }
        }
    }
    renderActivePaths(layerList[0]);
}





var brain = {
    counter: 0,
    layers: 3,
    globalReferenceNeurons: {},
    globalReferenceConnections: {},
}
var layer0 = [new Neuron(brain, 0), new Neuron(brain, 0), new Neuron(brain, 0),
    new Neuron(brain, 0), new Neuron(brain, 0), new Neuron(brain, 0), 
    new Neuron(brain, 0), new Neuron(brain, 0),new Neuron(brain, 0), 
    new Neuron(brain, 0)]; //10

var layer1 = [new Neuron(brain, 1), new Neuron(brain, 1), new Neuron(brain, 1), 
    new Neuron(brain, 1), new Neuron(brain, 1), new Neuron(brain, 1), 
    new Neuron(brain, 1), new Neuron(brain, 1), new Neuron(brain, 1),
    new Neuron(brain, 1), new Neuron(brain, 1), new Neuron(brain, 1),
    new Neuron(brain, 1)]; //13

var layer2 = [new Neuron(brain, 2), new Neuron(brain, 2)]; //2

layer0[0].connect(layer1[0]);
layer0[1].connect(layer1[1]);
layer0[2].connect(layer1[2]);
layer0[3].connect(layer1[3]);
layer0[4].connect(layer1[4]);
layer0[5].connect(layer1[5]);
layer0[6].connect(layer1[6]);
layer0[7].connect(layer1[7]);
layer0[8].connect(layer1[8]);
layer0[9].connect(layer1[9]);
layer0[0].connect(layer1[3]);
layer0[1].connect(layer1[4]);
layer0[2].connect(layer1[5]);
layer0[3].connect(layer1[6]);
layer0[4].connect(layer1[7]);
layer0[5].connect(layer1[8]);
layer0[6].connect(layer1[9]);
layer0[7].connect(layer1[10]);
layer0[8].connect(layer1[11]);
layer0[9].connect(layer1[12]);

layer1[0].connect(layer2[0]);
layer1[1].connect(layer2[1]);
layer1[2].connect(layer2[0]);
layer1[3].connect(layer2[1]);
layer1[4].connect(layer2[0]);
layer1[5].connect(layer2[1]);
layer1[6].connect(layer2[0]);
layer1[7].connect(layer2[1]);
layer1[8].connect(layer2[0]);
layer1[9].connect(layer2[1]);
layer1[10].connect(layer2[0]);
layer1[11].connect(layer2[1]);
layer1[12].connect(layer2[0]);

//works! until...

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
 return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

for (prop in brain.globalReferenceNeurons) {
 var rand = getRandomInt(1,6);
  var neuron = brain.globalReferenceNeurons[prop];
  if (rand == 1 && neuron.layer != 2) neuron.active = false;
}
for (prop in brain.globalReferenceConnections) {
 var rand = getRandomInt(1,6);
  var connection = brain.globalReferenceConnections[prop];
  if (rand == 1) connection.active = false;
}



renderBrain(brain, canvas.getContext("2d"), canvas);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width= 512 height = 200></canvas>
```

Comment: I waited to get home to test the accepted answer more fully before awarding the bounty for this reason. Checking it out now.

Comment: One issue with your answer, which I'm fixing in my own code but too big of a fix to show in a comment: `pos = node.id - layerList[node.layer][0].id;` The neuron ID can be 300. That means in your code (in a simulation of more than just a few neurons) you're rendering the neurons way off the screen. The ID has nothing to do with its position. So this just happens to look like it works in the fiddle because you arent looking at a simulation with hundreds of IDs. If there're a neuron with an ID of 300 on layer 2, it renders with an x coordinate of like > 2000.

Comment: I believe your code is working after the changes I made to the `nodePosition` method: https://jsfiddle.net/etz26r6e/1/ Maybe double check and update.

Answer (score 3):

```
for (var i1 = 0; i1 < targets.length; i1++) {
    var result = hasActivePathAhead(obj.connections[targets[count]].target, 
              count + 1);
    return result;
}
```

This snippet is weird. You may need this instead:

```
for (var i1 = 0; i1 < targets.length; i1++) {
    var result = hasActivePathAhead(obj.connections[targets[count]].target, 
              count + 1);
    if(result){
        return true;
    }        
}
```

And the usage of `count` is weird there. I think the `count` should not be  passed as a param, since it's used to index a target or source.

I think the snippet should be like this:

```
else if (targets.length) {
    var target;
    for (var i1 = 0; i1 < targets.length; i1++) {
        target=targets[i1];
        var result = hasActivePathAhead(obj.connections[target].target);
        if(result){
             return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

#### Live demo here:

```js
function Neuron(brain, layer) {
    var that = this;
    brain.counter++;
    brain.globalReferenceNeurons[brain.counter] = this;
    this.active = true; //as the brain mutates, some neurons and 
    //connections are disabled via this property
    this.layer = layer;
    this.id = brain.counter;
    this.connected = {};
    this.connections = {};
    this.connect = function (target) {
        if (that.active == true) {
            new Connection(brain, this, target, function (id, connection) {
                brain.globalReferenceConnections[id] = connection;
                that.connections[id] = connection;
            });
        }
    };
}

function Connection(brain, source, target, callback) {
    if (source.layer < target.layer) {
        brain.counter++;
        brain.globalReferenceConnections[brain.counter] = this;
        this.active = true; //as the brain mutates, some neurons and 
        //connections are disabled via this property
        this.id = brain.counter;
        this.source = source;
        this.target = target;
        target.connected[this.id] = this;
        callback(this.id, this);
    }
}


function renderBrain(brain, context, canvas) {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var width = canvas.width;
    var height = canvas.height;
    var layers = brain.layers;
    var heightDivision = height / layers;
    var layerList = [];
    for (var i1 = 0; i1 < brain.layers; i1++) {
        layerList.push([]);
        for (var prop1 in brain.globalReferenceNeurons) {
            if (brain.globalReferenceNeurons[prop1].layer === i1) {
                layerList[i1].push(brain.globalReferenceNeurons[prop1]);
            }
        }
    }

    function renderLayer(layer, layerCount, layerTotal) {
        var length = layer.length;
        var widthDivision = width / length;
        var neuronCount = 0;
        for (var i1 = 0; i1 < layer.length; i1++) {
            neuronCount++;
            const getActiveProps = obj => Object.keys(obj).filter(k => obj[k].active)

            function hasActivePathAhead(obj) {
                if (obj.active) {
                    var targets = getActiveProps(obj.connections);
                    if (obj.layer === 2) {
                        return true;
                    } else if (targets.length) {
                        var target;
                        for (var i1 = 0; i1 < targets.length; i1++) {
                            target = targets[i1];
                            var result = hasActivePathAhead(obj.connections[target].target);
                            if (result) {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            function hasActivePathBehind(obj) {
                if (obj.active) {
                    var sources = getActiveProps(obj.connected);
                    if (obj.layer === 0) {
                        return true;
                    } else if (sources.length) {
                        var source;
                        for (var i1 = 0; i1 < sources.length; i1++) {
                            source = sources[i1];
                            var result =
                                hasActivePathBehind(obj.connected[source].source);
                            return result;
                        }
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if (hasActivePathAhead(layer[i1]) && hasActivePathBehind(layer[i1])) {
                context.beginPath();
                context.arc((widthDivision * neuronCount) -
                    (0.5 * widthDivision),
                    (heightDivision * layerCount) -
                    (heightDivision * 0.5),
                    5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                context.fillStyle = '#adf442';
                context.fill();
                context.lineWidth = 2;
                context.strokeStyle = '#56cc41';
                context.stroke();
                var connectionCount = 0;
                for (var i2 = 0; i2 < Object.keys(layer[i1].connections).length; i2++) {
                    var connection =
                        layer[i1].connections[Object.keys(layer[i1].connections)[i2]];
                    if (hasActivePathAhead(connection.target) &&
                        hasActivePathBehind(connection.target)) {
                        var targetLayer = connection.target.layer;
                        var index = layerList[targetLayer].findIndex(function (e) {
                            return e == connection.target
                        });
                        if (index > -1) {
                            var targetLayerLength = Object.keys(layerList[targetLayer]).length;
                            var targetLayerWidthDivision = width / targetLayerLength;
                            var p1 = {
                                x: (widthDivision * neuronCount) - (0.5 * widthDivision),
                                y: (heightDivision * layerCount) - (heightDivision * 0.5)
                            };
                            var p2 = {
                                x: (index * targetLayerWidthDivision) +
                                    (0.5 * targetLayerWidthDivision),
                                y: (targetLayer * heightDivision) +
                                    (heightDivision * 0.5)
                            };
                            connectionCount++;
                            context.beginPath();
                            context.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
                            context.lineTo(p2.x, p2.y);
                            context.lineWidth = 1;
                            context.stroke();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    var layerCount = 0;
    for (i1 = 0; i1 < layerList.length; i1++) {
        layerCount++;
        renderLayer(layerList[i1], layerCount, layerList.length);
    }
}





var brain = {
    counter: 0,
    layers: 3,
    globalReferenceNeurons: {},
    globalReferenceConnections: {},
}
var layer0 = [new Neuron(brain, 0), new Neuron(brain, 0), new Neuron(brain, 0),new Neuron(brain, 0), new Neuron(brain, 0)];
var layer1 = [new Neuron(brain, 1), new Neuron(brain, 1), new Neuron(brain, 1)];
var layer2 = [new Neuron(brain, 2), new Neuron(brain, 2), new Neuron(brain, 2), new Neuron(brain, 2)];

layer0[0].connect(layer1[1]);
layer0[1].connect(layer1[0]);
layer0[3].connect(layer1[0]);
layer1[0].connect(layer2[0]);

layer1[2].connect(layer2[2]);
layer1[1].connect(layer2[3]);



var canvas = document.getElementById('cav');

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
renderBrain(brain, ctx, canvas);
```

```html
<canvas id="cav" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: I tested this (I applied the pattern shown to both `hasActivePathAhead` and `hasActivePathBehind`) and while it didn't throw any errors and didn't break anything, it didn't change much of anything in terms of rendering top-to-bottom full paths only. A appreciate your effort to help me. I understand this is difficult without being able to test your code so tomorrow Im going to generate a JSON brain structure to create an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I didnt consider that option before. Unfortunately it's too late at night and I cant do it until the morning.

Comment: I didnt want to expose my full source code and I thought maybe there was a small mistake people would be able to point out, but it's clear that I need to provide a test environment for you guys to effectively help me out. Which I just realized I can do without exposing the primary source. Thanks again for your effort so far. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @Viziionary  I added a live demo here. It  seems work as expected.

Comment: It works! until... you deactivate some random neurons or connections https://jsfiddle.net/au2Lt6na/4/ - that's where we're getting mixed up. Be sure you run the page a few times, depending on which neurons and connections are disabled, it'll be properly rendered sometimes, but usually not.

Comment: Note that either disabling some random neurons **or** connections will cause improper rendering, it doesn't even have to be both. Try disabling lines 223-227 to test that in the fiddle. Again, if you dont see a problem the first time, re-run a few times, you will eventually.

Comment: @Viziionary  Hey guy, you didn't correct your code completely. Try this:https://jsfiddle.net/blackmiaool/p9gm7k3L/

Comment: @Viziionary check L95

Comment: I'm on mobile (away from home for the weekend) but that new code you posted does seem to work. I'm pretty sure I just copied and pasted your code so Im confused about what you mean, but maybe I made a mistake.

Comment: @Viziionary `if(result){return true;}` This part you just copied once. You should copy twice. Check the line 95 of your jsfiddle.